# How can I make an HTTP request with no Content-Type header using django.test.Client?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http, http-headers

I have a Django application which must have the following behavior: if a request has no `Content-Type` header, it returns an error response.

In order to test this behavior, I need to make an HTTP request without a `Content-Type` header.

I am using [the `Client` class in the `django.test` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/). This has many methods, including this one:

> ```
> post(path, data=None, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT, follow=False, secure=False, **extra)
> ```
>
> Makes a POST request on the provided path and returns a Response object, which is documented below.
>
> [...]
>
> If you provide content_type (e.g. `text/xml` for an XML payload), the contents of data will be sent as-is in the POST request, using `content_type` in the HTTP `Content-Type` header.
>
> If you don’t provide a value for `content_type`, the values in data will be transmitted with a content type of `multipart/form-data`. In this case, the key-value pairs in data will be encoded as a multipart message and used to create the POST data payload.

The documentation says that a `Content-Type` header is always set on the request, irrespective of whether I pass a `content_type` argument.

So what other ways do I have to construct a request, such that it does not have a `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a customised request instance through the class [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory).

Once generated, you can modify the request instance before passing it to the view.

---

Using the example in the RequestFactory documentation page as a starting point, you can do:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from .views import my_view

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_details(self):
        # Create an instance of a POST request.
        request = self.factory.post('/your/url', data={'your':'data'})

        # NOW you can customise your request instance!
        # (i.e. remove the Content-Type header)
        request.META.pop('CONTENT_TYPE', None)

        # Actually use the request to test my_view() 
        # as if it were deployed at /customer/details
        response = my_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
```

The `request.META` is just a standard Python dictionary (as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)), so you can use

`del request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']`

instead of `pop()` to remove it, but only if you are deadly sure that the key will be in the dictionary.

Comment: If it's enough for you, another solution (faster, simpler, but dumber) is to have an "empty" Content-Type header. Simply pass an empty string to the content_type argument of the post() method.

`post('/some/url', data={'some': 'data'}, content_type='')`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several years old, but I had the same question and found the real answer, i.e. how to do this with the test client:

```
client.get(url, content_type=None)
```

At least on Django 2.0, that makes a request with no content type header.